# <h:outputStylesheet> doesn't render anything to HTML

Tags: html, css, jsf-2

I'm using JSF2 and primefaces, and cannot get the css sheet to load.

The CSS is stored @ WebContent/resources/css/style.css

xhtml:

```
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css" />
```

I've tried locating h:outputStylesheet within h:head and have also tried using the library="css" tag to no avail.

The output html as follows:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WireTapLogSearchUtility/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-home" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/WireTapLogSearchUtility/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WireTapLogSearchUtility/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.2"><!--//-->
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/WireTapLogSearchUtility/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.2"><!--//-->
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/WireTapLogSearchUtility/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces"><!--//--></script>
</head>
```

using ctrl+f on the source there is no results for style.css

Additionally I do have the mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Are you running the code you think you're running? Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart.

Comment: Wait ... The presence of those overzealous script comments in the generated HTML markup attempting to protect browsers which only existed around 1990 suggests that you're using MyFaces instead of Mojarra. Do you have set `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` context param to `Development`? If not, then you indeed need to restart the whole server on every single edit of the XHTML file, because MyFaces caches compiled XHTML files by default infinitely.

Comment: Hi BalusC I've been restarting the server after every update. And no I have not set it to development although I have just done so. How do I know if I'm using MyFaces or Mojarra? I was told by my reviewer to remove all references to apache MyFaces from web.xml

Comment: JSF impl make/version is usually just during startup printed to server log. Well, if restarting doesn't solve the problem, then I don't know. The cause is not visible in the information provided so far.

Comment: Ah checked console: It appears I am using MyFaces, and I recieve the error:
WARNING: Resource referenced by resourceName css/styles.css not found in call to ResourceHandler.createResource. It will be silenty ignored.

Comment: Look, there's your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I've made a SCHOOLBOY error... I named the css sheet as style.css, and was referencing styleS.css. My colleague came over and spotted it in two seconds! Thanks for all your help Balus, if  hadn't enabled dev mode and seen the error would probably have spent the whole day on this!

Answer (score 0):

The tags h:outputScript and/or h:outputStylesheet do not render anything if the resource can not be found on disk. Test the URl with:

http://localhost:8080/MyApp/javax.faces.resource/css/mycss.css

where "MyApp" is a name of your servlet and "mycss.css" name of the file contained in the folder "resources/css/". If you do not get 404 then <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="mycss.css"></h:outputStylesheet> should work fine